# Frequency attack, characters displayed incorrectly when trying to print them (upper is lower, and lower is upper)

Tags: java, encryption, character

I'm working on a frequency attack to obtain the encryption key of a text. I wrote one, however the key obtained is almost identical to the one used, however, upper chars are now lower, and lower chars are upper. Moreover, numbers aren't even displayed. I don't really how to fix this issue.

This is the involed code:

```
    public static char[] encryptionKey = new char[4];
    public static String letters = "0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static char[] stringToCharArray(String str){
        char[] res = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            res[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void G(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            Random random = new Random();
            encryptionKey[i] = letters.charAt(random.nextInt(letters.length()));
        }
    }

    public static String E(String clearText){
        char[] clearTextChars = stringToCharArray(clearText);
        char[] encryptedTextChars = new char[clearTextChars.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < clearTextChars.length; i++){
            encryptedTextChars[i] = (char) (clearTextChars[i] ^ encryptionKey[i % 4]);
        }
        return new String(encryptedTextChars);
    }

    public static String D(String encryptedText){
        char[] encryptedTextChars = stringToCharArray(encryptedText);
        char[] clearTextChars = new char[encryptedTextChars.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedTextChars.length; i++){
            clearTextChars[i] = (char) (encryptedTextChars[i] ^ encryptionKey[i % 4]);
        }
        return new String(clearTextChars);
    }

    public static char maxOccuringChar(String text){
        int[] counter = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            counter[text.charAt(i)]++;
        }
        int max = -1;
        char res = ' ';
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            if (max < counter[text.charAt(i)]){
                max = counter[text.charAt(i)];
                res = text.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static String[] splitString(String str){
        String[] parts = new String[4];
        parts[0] = "";
        parts[1] = "";
        parts[2] = "";
        parts[3] = "";
        char[] strChars = stringToCharArray(str);
        for (int i = 0; i < strChars.length; i++){
            parts[i%4] += strChars[i];
        }
        return parts;
    }

    public static char[] maxOccOnParts(String[] parts){
        char[] possibleKey = new char[4];
        possibleKey[0] = maxOccuringChar(parts[0]);
        System.out.println("p1 ->"+(int) possibleKey[0]);
        possibleKey[1] = maxOccuringChar(parts[1]);
        System.out.println("p2 ->"+(int) possibleKey[1]);
        possibleKey[2] = maxOccuringChar(parts[2]);
        System.out.println("p3 ->"+(int) possibleKey[2]);
        possibleKey[3] = maxOccuringChar(parts[3]);
        System.out.println("p4 ->"+(int) possibleKey[3]);

        return possibleKey;
    }

    public static void printEncryptionKey(){
        System.out.println("Encryption key : "+ new String(encryptionKey));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        G();
        printEncryptionKey();
        String test = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
        // System.out.println("Length = "+test.length());
        // System.out.println("Split = "+test.length()/4);
        String testEncrypted = E(test);
        String testDecrypted = D(testEncrypted);
        System.out.println("String : " + test);
        System.out.println("Encrypted : " + testEncrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted : " + testDecrypted);
        String[] strArray = splitString(testEncrypted);
        for (String str : strArray) {
          System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println("MaxOccuringChar per split part");
        char[] key = maxOccOnParts(strArray);
        for (char ch : key){
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
    }
```

This is one of the output this code can create:

```
Encryption key : 3Gad
String : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Encrypted : (^g(@2
                  DZ4AZJg^*DG"(DG/DC5
G.&3V4G..F4JiA(\5       F*A
                           R4AV"DG/DZ)@34AG&R5DW2
                                                        JgK3AE"D@.Vg
                                                                    VgPQwH0     ]g
2](
]33
V>AXgDT&
^"DQ(g(/4E.Wg   Q+.DG(A R,DRgC"AC"
             Gg
_>AZ1DP"F@kAF3A_4DG/D_".\V$\3V4G.g^&
Z)DV4]_+DF)
           R)WiA-Gg@g
A.Wg                 C2
R4D\!A(V3@"D@/G4A\)Z)"
Tg-
   A"
G/AV4Dz7^g@4V4MDR)D^(5VJg
@/AF%
Tg
  U3A"Z,Dr+@g1T",X"DZF#
TgA4
   ]4A
      Ug-
         A"
#7^>AV?D\!A["AA.Z)DR)DG>@"Z)DZ)@3g-
                                   A"
]#G5C@gR)A#AF*                       Dz7^g      @gV)A["A
              3GgV5AZ)3 vTT4MDD/
&DF)

\0DC5
Jg3Vg&AR+
WgA&
    _"DZ3A\g
            X"A3VgV$    V)A\(
E"AV)A.gG@(A["V&DZ)
P3                 "
] A@4G>@"Z)H5   R.
G/A["AV+@"A(07F+Z4.DG/D~WT@g
           Ug-G5V3A["@g
].                     ]3
[g@,A-C4        7@&@kA]#A       \5DA"]3
X"A%_#V[.4G0Vg
W.1@.
@g
  V*A-C4
Decrypted : Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
^@ZZJ^GGCGVGFJ\FRVGZ@GRWJKE@VV]]]XTVUC]PQGRRCC^QEWG_ZPF@F_G_\V\VG^ZV]_FRWG@CAWZGAR\V@@G\ZTAz^@VR^VJGV\F@TUAZr@TXZFTA]UAz^\F@^^V\[AZRG@ZZ@Az^@V[]G@RAFGVZDF\CGGRJVWA_Z\XVVV\[@ZJEVAG@[VZP]G@ZR]@G_]]FZG@G[V@UGV[@]]VC@@]\A][@CQ[GVX_VV]W@@VC
(g24*g*"(/5.&34..4i5*4"/)34&52g3".ggw0g2(733g&>g"#5+.(,g"""(g/4.gg>1"5k34/".g$)34.g&)43+))igg2.g3v43/"4!3"/4))g"7g44)(5)g/47%/g3",+g"")#g44g"7i5*g7#>?!".))>"))3g"7gg)"#5g)#*3g5)3v4/&)05"(&+g3gg&"3g"3g$)(&21)(g").gg("&)"3.>")5. 4.>$ g07+4./~g/"+"g53"g3.
                                              *47&k#5"30g,g+.40g"#
5$.1.g
      *4
(
 AAAA
A-AAAAAA
  MA
AA-
AAA-A
        AAA
           A    TM
A
A
 A
AAA     (WAAA-AAAA
DDD
(
  DDD   D
         QH


D
DD      D

DDD
DD
  -

RDDD(D

DDD

DD



DDDDD
CTD  D
D
D
D
D JDD

 DH
DDT

-       D
%
-
MaxOccuringChar per split part
Encryption key found:
p1 ->19
p2 ->103
p3 ->65
p4 ->68

g
A
D
```

We can see that the chars are "inverted" compared to the original encryption key at the top, and that the number isn't displayed, but I printed the int value of those chars to see if I could find something... I didn't.

I honestly don't know when this problem starts nor how to fix it. The expected output would be the encryption key used here at the beginning of the output. I guess my attack is working, because it's the same letters.

What would recommend to fix that problem please?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that 19 is 0x13, while you are looking for 0x33. And there is only one bit difference: 0x20: the same bit that converts an `A`: 0x41 to an `a`: 0x61. Coincidence? I think NOT!

Comment: Oh very good observation. @MaartenBodewes So I'm losing a bit somewhere. I honestly don't know where. But I could just add a bit at the final result then? Is that possible in Java you think?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I ended up trying adding 0x20 to my characters in `maxOccOnParts`, it works great for finding back the numbers if there are any in the key, but it still doesn't solve the problem of having upper and lower chars inverted...

Comment: Well, I guess you need to have some kind of indication which characters may be upper and lowercase in the plaintext to solve that. `Lorum` also has an uppercase character. If you don't care about the casing then you may have multiple valid keys after all for a classical cipher. Or you may have additional restrictions for valid key characters of course.